# TypeError: Cannot read property '$destroy' of undefined angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have Logout controller

```
 .controller("AuthLogoutCtrl", function($state) {
        localStorage.clear();
        $state.transitionTo("login");
    });
```

On Which when I reach It Throws Below Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$destroy' of undefined
at Object.headerBarInstance.destroy (ionic.bundle.js:47548)
at ionic.bundle.js:47912
at Scope.$broadcast (ionic.bundle.js:23412)
at Scope.$destroy (ionic.bundle.js:23032)
at Scope.scopePrototype.$destroy (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1943)
at Object.destroyViewEle (ionic.bundle.js:46743)
at self.transitionEnd (ionic.bundle.js:48099)
at ionic.bundle.js:46630
at forEach (ionic.bundle.js:9015)
at ionicViewSwitcher.transitionEnd (ionic.bundle.js:46629)
```

Below is Login Controller Code

```
 .controller("AuthLoginCtrl",function($scope, $state, AuthSvcs, Toast, ApartmentData, $localstorage, $ionicLoading) {
        if ($localstorage.get("Login")) {
            $state.transitionTo("app.settings.SelectCommunity", {
                url: "login"
            });
        }
```

Please Suggest Something Not Able to Identify what I am doing wrong i am using ionic framework

Comment: Look for $scope.$destroy in one of your views / directives.

Comment: I'm using ionic it have 1000 of directives

Comment: Isn't it ionic? Don't you think? :) Look in your views and custom directives. You're killing the scope somewhere, and try to invoke $scope.$destroy.